# Oracle: need a query to fetch data for certain range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**data table**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| id    start_range     end_range    descr  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1        500            550         data1 |
| 2        500            500         data2 |
| 3        510            510         data3 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

So i need help with making a query that will input a range value and will check for start and end range, if it lies in the range then should return row accordingly.

For ex.

```
input: 500 output: data2
input: 510 output: data3
input: 502 output: data1
input: 550 output: data1
input: 551 output: null
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: So ranges can overlap. And if a value matches two ranges (as 500 matches both 500-550 and 500-500), what range to pick? The smaller range (i.e. 500-500, as it contains only 1 number, whereas 500-550 contains 51)? But what in case of ties then? 500 is in 450-500 and in 500-550. Or do you want a completely different algorithm on how to pick the range from several? Define the rules.

Comment: If i enter then it should pick range of 500-500 as it exactly matches the range, if i enter 501 then it should pick 500-550 range... and again if i enter 510 then it should pick 510-510 and ignore 500-550 range..so in range there is possibility of getting some input which exactly matches the range and only contains 1 number as said.. so it should pick the closest set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your query fails if i input 510; then it will return data for both 510-510 range as well as 500-550 range

Comment: So there are never overlapping ranges like 400-410 and 405-415? The only overlapping ever to occur is that there are real ranges, such as 500-550, and single-number "ranges, such as 500-500. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes there is not going to be any overlapping range like 400-410 and 405 to 415 ... there can only be a single number range in between a big range.. as mentioned 500-500 and 500-550..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added plsql as this query is required inside a procedure i am making, so even if i get a plsql block used to solve this using if-else or some thing, then it will be fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get

- one match for a number as 510 in 500-550
- several matches as 500 both in 500-500 and 500-550
- no match as for 551

So you'd have to pick the record you consider "best" from your matches. One way to do this is ranking your matches with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select descr 
from
(
  select descr,
    row_number() over (order by end_range - start_range) as rn
  from mytable
  where @value between start_range and end_range
)
where rn = 1;
```

This gives you a row with the "best" description, or no row when there is no match.

Another option is Oracle's `KEEP DENSE_RANK`:

```
select max(descr) keep (dense_rank first order by end_range - start_range)
from mytable
where @value between start_range and end_range;
```

This gives you the "best" description, or NULL when there is no match.